# Powershell test 2 statements if true functions

Tags: function, powershell, if-statement

```
Clear-Host
Function First {
    $File1 = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"
    $TestFile1 = Test-Path $File1
    If ($TestFile1 -eq $True) {Write-Host "Winrar is installed." -F Green -B Black}
    Else {Write-Host "Winrar is not installed." -F Red -B Black}
}
First

Function Second {
    $winrar = Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
    $winrarCheck = "Winrar"
    $winrarFinal = $winrar | Where {$_.DisplayName -match $winrarCheck} | Format-Table -Property DisplayName,DisplayVersion

    $winrarFinal
    If ($winrarFinal) {Write-Host "Winrar registry check installed." -F Green -B Black}
    Else {Write-Host "Winrar registry check failed." -F Red -B Black}
    }
Second
```

Is there a way to check both functions with If statement? I want to check it like if both functions are true, 
`Write-Host "Program installed." Else Write-Host "Failed to install".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
Function CheckFileInstalled {

    param (
        [string]$pathProg     = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe",
        [string]$nameProg     = "Winrar"
    )

    $testFileProg = Test-Path $pathProg

    $x86 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
        Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$nameProg*" } ).Length -gt 0;

    $x64 = ((Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") |
        Where-Object { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$nameProg*" } ).Length -gt 0;


    return ( $testFileProg -and ($x86 -or $x64) )

}


if( CheckFileInstalled ) {

    Write-Host "Program installed." 
}
else {
    Write-Host "Failed to install."
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, would you please explain this line?  return ( $testFileProg -or $x86 -or $x64 )

Comment: If one of them is true, function returns true

Comment: Is there a way to make it like 2 of them are true, return true? I need the $testfileProg to be true and either 1 of $x86 or $x64

Comment: return ( $testFileProg -and ($x86 -or $x64) )

Comment: F6a4, is there a reason for this part of the code? ).Length -gt 0;?

Comment: The returned value from get-childItem / where is a string. And if something is found, length of the string is greater than 0.

Comment: Does it translate the get-childitem plus where-object to "True or False"?

Comment: I purposely entered a typo in the { $_.GetValue( "DisplayName" ) -like "*$nameProg*" }. I changed the "*$nameProg*" to "*$nameProgram*" and the result still gave me True....